# Stacks and Objects (Public Classes)

Tags: java

I need a container to keep track of a bunch of objects (`public class Note`), and a `Stack` seems to be perfect for what I need. The container's called `listOfNotes`. But when I try to push a Note onto the stack with:

```
listofNotes.push(Note0),
```

the compiler gives me this error:

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to push(E) as a member of the raw type Stack.

Does this mean stacks can't hold objects, or am I using the command "push" wrong?

Comment: Please post a sample of your code illustrating the issue.

Comment: You have to define the Type e.g. List<String> means you are defining a type of this list to string. You might want to List<Node> or what ever your class is called.

Comment: It means the declaration of your stack does not specify what type of objects it can hold.  It is anyway a *warning*, not an error.

Comment: Please post your full corpus of code here, formatted properly (via Ctrl+K). From the sounds of things, you've declared `listOfNotes` as a `Stack` (with no generic type argument) instead of a `Stack<Note>`. Please look into [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), since all language-provided container classes use generics (since Java 1.5/J2SE 5.0).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the Type e.g.

```
List<String>
```

means you are defining a type of this list to string. You might want to

```
List<Node>
```

or what ever your class is called.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say without a code sample but something like this should work:

```
 Stack stack = new Stack();
 Note note = new Note();
 stack.push(note);
```

Can you give a fuller code sample?

Answer (score 0):

It's only a **warning** (not an error) and everything's ok.
You may advise the compiler to ignore that kind of warning, for example by using the annotation @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") in your code. Do so, if it **IS** ok for you. In that case you may need to cast when popping from the Stack, like that:

```
Note note = (Note) listOfNotes.pop();
```

But for better style and usability you should consider to give the container (Stack) the intended type (see 'Generics'):

```
package yourpackage;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Note {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Stack<Note> listOfNotes = new Stack<>();
        listOfNotes.push(new Note());
    }
}
```

So the code for retrieving Objects from the Stack is like that:

```
Note note = listOfNotes.pop();
```